# How to compare two times in hh:mm AM/PM format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I am using a plugin that will produce times in the format of hh:mm AM/PM.
   I want to compare them using jQuery/javascript.
2. If user entering the time manually, the text in the textbox will automatically                                            rearrange to hh:mm AM/PM(need space between time and AM/PM).
   i.e I need a regular expression that will execute in keyup/keydown, that will allow only alphabets AM/PM at the end of string.

please provide me a solution.

Comment: please write the code that you have been tried

Comment: I would consider looking at [`momentjs`](http://momentjs.com/). You'd instantiate two `moment`s, and use some of the [query functions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/).

Comment: *"alphabets AM/PM"*, what's that? Also SO isn't a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this js regex `/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/` to validate the AM/PM Format, call this in your keyup/keydown event.

```
var value = $(this).val().match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/);
```